# Python 3 and Selenium, submit button not clickable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, submit, selenium-chromedriver

I know that there are similar questions asked about element not clickable issue but for me didn't worked any proposed solution. Mainly I am using Chromedriver and sometimes Geckodriver, this appear on both.

Still getting, Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (470, 1499)

even as you can see I tried with find_element.click() and also with action chains.

More confusing in my case is that part with ("M_1_anchor") pass and part with ("submit") fail, not clickable. Just to add another confusion, same function worked fine till middle of August 2017.

My function is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def select_and_click_edit_contact_details(self):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
    action = ActionChains(self.driver)
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "M_1_anchor")))
    self.driver.find_element_by_id("M_1_anchor").click()

  action.move_to_element(self.driver.find_element_by_id("submit")).perform()
    action.click(self.driver.find_element_by_id("submit")).perform()
    #self.driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
```

I admit that submit button is not optically visible on page and user need to scroll down but that shouldn't be reason for failing.

```
    </select></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#report">
                    Report
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="report" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-xs-2 col-md-3 control-label">
                        Image file of your logo
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-9">
 <img class="img img-responsive" src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9k=" width="100">                        </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        <label class="col-xs-2 col-md-3 control-label">
                            Footer text on driver accounting
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-9">
                            <p class="form-control-static">
                                20
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-
      toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#cashbox">
                        Cashbox
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="cashbox" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Currently there are no cashboxes defined!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </label>
    </div>
  </form></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $("#list option").attr('disabled', true);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(
                                 {
                                     showContent: false
                                 });
      });
   </script>
   </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="push"></div>
 </div>
   <script src="/HaleWebApplication/bundles/DatatablesNewJs?
  v=83AITBTc8vgdDH09rqjGm5-sSopLGkHfDID5YpRCCVs1"></script>
<script src="/HaleWebApplication/bundles/TreeviewJs?
v=p6JgEssUYL1w3zZdiBDt4Ul_VWhmdclj9e1PSoZpKWI1"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the button is visible after `move_to_element(#submit)`?

Comment: I am not sure (see attached screenshot). It doesn't work with find_element_by_id or xpath either and it should even is not visible it is on the page.

Comment: Can you paste the relevant html here? You've attached a screenshot, but how do we associate your problem/code with it? Have you checked if the submit is not disabled when you intend to click it?

Comment: HTML added to question description

Comment: when I use this combination    without  action.click() still the same, that means that action.move step pass.
     
          action.move_to_element(#submit).perform()
          #action.click(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)).perform()
          self.driver.find_element_by_id(#submit).click()

Comment: @domoni Is this a web page or a tab/pop-up in a web page? if so do you have in the same page/tab other submit button? because some time you have multiple tabs with a button with the same name/id and when you try to search it selenium find it but really find the 1 in the list that can be in another tab so selenium find but it's not able to click. if this is the case you should make a multiple selection, take all the button with the same name/id and then understand which one is yours. if you give me more details I can help you, it's not a selector problem but the way of how is implemented the UI

Comment: It is a web page with formular which can be edited and saved. There is only one result for id="submit" in HTML body, so only one Edit/Save (submit) button

Comment: Maybe, is the button inside a iframe?

Comment: Can you please paste a bit broader html? Alternatively, can you confirm if the controls that you've shown in screenshot (e.g. vehicle no. text box) are inside a `FORM` html tag? If so, does replacing your `action.click(xxx).perform()` with `element.submit()` work (the latter is shortcut way to submit a form without clicking the submit button)?

Comment: Broader html added, please let me know if that is enough or should I paste whole body? Can it be that some new Chrome version affected webdrivers behavior?

Comment: Yes, changes in Chrome, chromedriver or selenium versions could affect actionChains. Elements displaying on top of your Submit button could cause this behavior. You could pre-check it after you move it into view with expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) or even for it to be visible (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of)

Comment: I did that "element_to_be_clickable" without success, but now I got different message when usig FF Geckodriver

MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (517.816650390625, 1413.2583465576172) is out of bounds of viewport width (1268) and height (845)

Comment: When I put "expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable" instead of "actionChains_move_to_element" and run it under FF Geckodriver it worked fine. So it is Chromedriver problem or Chrome problem, but I don't know exact where to open a bug to Chromedriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at the end solution was to downgrade Chrome version from 61 to 60 and upgrade ChromeDriver from 2.31 to 2.33. it is important to synchronize browser and webdriver versions. Thank all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

When I put "expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable" instead of "actionChains_move_to_element" and run it under FF Geckodriver it worked fine. So it is Chromedriver problem or Chrome problem, but I don't know exact where or what is causing that. If someone could help me to identify it and open a bug to Chromedriver, would be much thankful.